# Split Ruby array into sub array with slash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have got an Array:

```
a = [[676, "/"], [679, "/", 680, "/"], [4, "3.7", "111.55", "/"], [668, "/"], [681, "/", 682, "/"]]
```

Want to have an output  like:

```
a = [[676], [679], [680], [4, "3.7", "111.55"], [668], [681], [682]]
```

Have Tried something like this:

```
a.flatten.join(",").split("/")
```

which gives something like this:

```
["676,", ",679,", ",680,", ",4,3.7,111.55,", ",668,", ",681,", ",682,"]
```

Comment: This is a terrible problem, and there's no simple answer here - you'd need to iterate over the array doing it manually.  Seems like maybe you should rewind a step and show what your real problem is (ie. where did this data come from in the first place).

Comment: @smathy I wouldn't say that, I posted two rather simple answers and the the one by mu is pretty readable too.

Comment: Yeah, you pwnd me.  Nicely played :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
a.flatten.chunk { |x| x != '/' }.select(&:first).map(&:last)  
#=> [[676], [679], [680], [4, "3.7", "111.55"], [668], [681], [682]]
```

Alternatively:

```
a.flatten.chunk { |x| x != '/' }.map { |bool, arr| arr if bool }.compact
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit messy (as smathy said it's a nasty problem), and probably not very flexible to change, but:

```
 arr = [[676­, "/"],­ [679,­ "/", 680, "/"],­ [4, "3.7"­, "111.­55", "/"],­ [668,­ "/"],­ [681,­ "/", 682, "/"]]­
arr.i­nject([]) do |res,­ el|
  tmp = []
  el.ea­ch do |inne­r_el|
    if inner­_el == "/"
      res << tmp
      tmp = []
    else
      tmp << inner­_el
    end
  end
  res
end
```

Comment: +1 for reading the question :) You can simplify this a fair bit by flattening the initial array before doing anything else though.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is certainly cleaner than my primary school attempt ;)

Comment: But Michael Kohl's is better still!

Comment: Indeed it is, +1 to both of ya :)

Answer (score 1):

The original arrays don't seem to matter so we can use `flatten` to simplify the `inject`:

```
a.flatten
 .inject([[]]) { |m, e| e == '/' ? m.push([]) : m.last.push(e); m }
 .reject(&:empty?)
```

The final `reject` is needed to get rid of the stray empty array from the final `"/"`.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
a.map!{|x| x.reject{|x| x=='/'}}
```

This will work..